# How to join two dataframes with an unequal number of rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I want to join two dataframes `info` and `store` . `Info` contains around 1 million rows and information about sales on different dates of a certain store on that day using ID represented in `Store` column of info dataframe, there are 1115 different stores. `store` dataframe contains information about that store with it's certain features, `store` dataframe also contain store ID column as `Store`. I want to join both dataframes such that new dataframe contains all the features of both with data, sales, also information about store from `store` dataframe.

I tried `.join`, `.merge` methods but these are working fine till 1115th row but after that it is giving null values.

`Info` Dataframe

```
   Store  DayOfWeek  Date        Sales  Customers  Open  Promo  StateHoliday  SchoolHoliday
   -----  ---------  ----------  -----  ---------  ----  -----  ------------  -------------
0      1          5  2015-07-31   5263        555     1      1             0              1
1      2          5  2015-07-31   6064        625     1      1             0              1
2      3          5  2015-07-31   8314        821     1      1             0              1
3      4          5  2015-07-31  13995       1498     1      1             0              1
4      5          5  2015-07-31   4822        559     1      1             0              1
```

`store` Dataframe

```
   Store  StoreType  Assortment  CompetitionDistance  CompetitionOpenSinceMonth  CompetitionOpenSinceYear  Promo2  Promo2SinceWeek  Promo2SinceYear  PromoInterval  
   -----  ---------  ----------  -------------------  -------------------------  ------------------------  ------  ---------------  ---------------  ---------------
0      1  c          a                          1270                          9                      2008       0  NaN              NaN              NaN            
1      2  a          a                           570                         11                      2007       1  13               2010             Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
2      3  a          a                         14130                         12                      2006       1  14               2011             Jan,Apr,Jul,Oct
3      4  c          c                           620                          9                      2009       0  NaN              NaN              NaN            
4      5  a          a                         29910                          4                      2015       0  NaN              NaN              NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `left_join` function from package `dplyr` or `tidyverse`.

Based on your data, you could use:
`joinedDf = left_join(Info, store, by = c("Store" = "Store")`.

Note that I also encountered peculiar NA values in the joined dataframe, which is something that I cannot explain yet. However, if you are sure that those NA lines are useless, just use `joinedDf = joinedDf[complete.cases(joinedDf), ]` to remove lines with NA.

Answer (score 0):

You do want to perform a join, but it sounds like you weren't specifying the column on which to join.

Sample data:

`info`

```
   Year  Week  Store  Sales
0  2018     1      1   1011
1  2018     2      1   1021
2  2018     1      2   1012
3  2018     2      2   1022
```

`store`

```
   Store StoreName StoreCity
0      1    store1     city1
1      2    store2     city2
```

The default for `.join` is to join on the *indexes* of the DataFrames, so

```python
joined = info.join(store, lsuffix='_from_info')
```

produces a DataFrame in which only the first two rows "match" (indexes 0 and 1)

```
   Year  Week  Store_from_info  Sales  Store StoreName StoreCity
0  2018     1                1   1011    1.0    store1     city1
1  2018     2                1   1021    2.0    store2     city2
2  2018     1                2   1012    NaN       NaN       NaN
3  2018     2                2   1022    NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Notice that the second row of the result (index 1) has joined `info` data for store1 (`Store_from_info` is 1) with `store` data for store2. That's not what you want.

Instead, you want to join on the `Store` columns in each DataFrame. That can be done with

```python
joined = info.join(store.set_index('Store'), on='Store')
```

producing

```
   Year  Week  Store  Sales StoreName StoreCity
0  2018     1      1   1011    store1     city1
1  2018     2      1   1021    store1     city1
2  2018     1      2   1012    store2     city2
3  2018     2      2   1022    store2     city2
```

See the pandas [.join documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) for details.